# Lock Cells Based on Conditionally Formatted Interior Color

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am working on a project that requires locked cells based on how the cells are conditionally formatted. In this instance the conditionally formatted cells have interior color 15.

This is the rule I am using for the conditional formatting:

IF: `=($D$2+$M8)>=(V$1)`

APPLIES TO: `$V$8:$AG$229,$AI$8:$AT$229,$AW$8:$BH$229,$BJ$8:$BU$229`

FORMAT: Interior Color Code 15

I need a VBA code that will lock all the cells on the entire sheet that have that conditional formatting applied.  Since the color of the cells is based on a conditional format, none of the VBA codes I can find will recognize the color.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Look into [DisplayFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat)

Comment: Or better yet just do the actual same test in the code. `If A+ B > C then`

Comment: That you for reaching out Scott.  Here is the thing, I am not very well versed in writing the code.

Comment: Well, there is the problem.  This site is not a code for me site.  It will help overcome specific problems with existing code.

Comment: nevermind....i fixed it.  thanks for your help.  I wasn't intending for someone to write the code for me but the link you sent help me fix it....two little words "DisplayFormat" fixed the code.  Thank you again!